# Imagem remota recebida por CURL e reduzida no PHP

Tags: php, libcurl

O código abaixo teoricamente seria para reduzir a largura e altura das imagens [**FORMATO JPG SOMENTE**] recebidas pelo CURL e armazenar no servidor, porém a imagem criada é apenas uma imagem nas medidas de 800x600 com fundo preto, o que pretendi fazer era somente redimensionar as imagens para o servidor não armazenar as imagens de tamanho original pega do servidor remoto devido ao tamanho que são imagens grandes que para a finalidade não tem necessidade e economizaria também espaço em disco.

```
$urlImg = 'https://images.site.com/image.jpg';

$url  = $urlImg;

$imgName = str_replace(":","",$url);
$imgName = str_replace("//","",$imgName);
$imgName = str_replace("/","",$imgName);
$imgName = str_replace("_","",$imgName);

$path = './upload/' . $imgName;
$curl = curl_init();
$ch   = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_URL            => $url,
//  CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER => 1, --- No effect from PHP 5.1.3
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_FILE           => $file,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 50,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)'
]);

$data  = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

$im    = imagecreatefromstring($data);

$x     = 800;
$y     = 600;

$im2   = imagecreatetruecolor($x,$y);

imagecopyresized($im2,$im,0,0,0,0,$x,$y,imagesx($im),imagesy($im));

imagecopyresampled($im2,$im,0,0,0,0,$x,$y,imagesx($im),imagesy($im));

$returnCreateImage = imagejpeg($im2, $path);

if ( $returnCreateImage ) {

    imagedestroy($im);
    imagedestroy($im2);
    echo "[Get]\n";

}
```

O código funcionava do modo que queria antes da modificação para reduzir as imagens, que é este abaixo.

```
$urlImg = 'https://images.site.com/image.jpg';

$url  = $urlImg;

$imgName = str_replace(":","",$url);
$imgName = str_replace("//","",$imgName);
$imgName = str_replace("/","",$imgName);
$imgName = str_replace("_","",$imgName);

$path = './upload/' . $imgName;

$curl = curl_init();

$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Update as of PHP 5.4 array() can be written []
curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_URL            => $url,
//  CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER => 1, --- No effect from PHP 5.1.3
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_FILE           => $file,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 50,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)'
]);

$data = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

if(file_put_contents($path, $data)) {

    echo "[Get]\n";

}
```

Comment: Caro Eliseu, deixa eu tirar uma duvida, você quer converter a imagem para JPEG e colocar o fundo que seria anteriormente transparente para branco ou deseja manter a transparencia de fato? É que isto não ficou evidente/claro em sua pergunta, ps: o downvote não é meu, mas o motivo talvez tenha sido essa falta de detalhamento do que realmente precisa. Fico no aguardo ;)

Comment: Oi, editei a pergunta, a intenção somente é redimensionar a original recebida pelo CURL e armazenar pois é desnecessário o tamanho original do servidor remoto para a finalidade e também economizará espaço em disco. =D

Comment: Deixe-me ver se entendi, você quer redimensionar qualquer tipo de imagem de qualquer formato e apenas salvar em seu servidor, seria isto?

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que isto ocorra porque está salvando JPEG e não PNG. Em tese o JPEG não suporta transparência, digo "em tese" porque ele parece suportar, mas não é tão comum usar tal recurso.

Além disso, você está usando o `imagecreatetruecolor` que cria uma imagem preta, por padrão.

---

Eu não tenho PHP para testar, estou me baseando apenas na documentação.

```
$original = imagecreatefromstring($data);

// Os tamanhos das imagens:
[$cx, $cy] = [800, 600];
[$ox, $oy] = [imagesx($original), imagesy($original)];

// Cria a imagem:
$comprimido = imagecreatetruecolor($cx,$cy);

// Define a imagem para transparente:
imagefill($comprimido, 0, 0, imagecolorallocatealpha($comprimido, 0, 0, 0, 127));

// Habilita a transparência:
imagealphablending($comprimido, false);
imagesavealpha($comprimido, true);

imagecopyresized($comprimido, $original, 0, 0, 0, 0, $cx, $cy, $ox, $oy);
imagecopyresampled($comprimido, $original, 0, 0, 0, 0, $cx, $cy, $ox, $oy);

// Salva como PNG (não JPEG):
$returnCreateImage = imagepng($comprimido, $path);
```

Isto deve ser o suficiente, mas não posso testar. Creio que, mesmo que não funciona, o problema ser relacionado ao PNG.

Comment: Apenas como nota para detalhes sobre JPEG e transparencia: A transparencia em JPEG se refere ao JPEG 2000 e as funções PHP parece que só suporta o JPEG200 para obter "tamanho", vejam: como dito em https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.image.php, não encontrei menção sobre o jpeg2000 nas demais funções do GD, o que provavelmente se refere ao getimagesize e não ao GD, então mesmo que jpeg2000 suporte transparencia, não é a mesma coisa que jpeg e pelo teste que fiz o imagejpeg não suporta salvar com o alpha, ficando um fundo preto em seu lugar.

Comment: Nota ²: Talvez o imagick (nome usado no PHP que se refere ao `ImageMagick`) tenha suporte para JPEG2000, mas também não é bem documentado, claro que tanto o GD quanto o ImageMagick são parte de outras coisas e não interno do PHP, então talvez no site oficial do ImageMagick deve detalhar o suporte (que existe) só tem que conferir se a versão usada no PHP é equivalente a que tem suporte e se as funções do php tem suporte com os parametros, mas lembra-se que para instalar ele somente via pecl, você pode até tentar instalar manualmente por você mesmo, o que provavelmente é bem trabalhoso.

Comment: oi, deixei a desejar na explicação, é somente formato jpg mesmo, e redimensionar o tamanho da original para armazenar somente.

Comment: @EliseuB.O problema é justamente a imagem original, ela é um PNG, com transparência, ao menos no seu exemplo. Você disse que havia um fundo preto, então deduzi que a imagem não estava mantendo o fundo transparente. Se a imagem original é PNG, seria preferível que a imagem redimensionada também fosse.

Comment: Entendi, a img não é PNG mesmo, é apenas JPG, foi uma infelicidade pegar uma imagem da web para colocar no exemplo kkkkk